# User input to database

Tags: php, mysql, pattern-matching, mysql-real-escape-string

Suppose that, we're expecting just strings or numbers with the data send by a user. Is it safe enough to check the data with ereg and preg_match functions? Is there a way to fake them? Should we still use mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: `ereg` is bad (deprecated) and usually enforcing a proper type (casting with `(int)`) is better (you cannot accidentally allow something bad) and even easier than validating unless you have a nice library doing all the validation for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

safe enough is relative to your own needs. If you're wanting to avoid mysql_real_escape_string for some reason then I first want to ask why.

My answer is: sure... depending on your conditions

you can preg match against [0-9a-z] and there is nothing to fear. Try passing a multibyte character to be safe. So long as your condition does not allow you to do anything if the match does not fit your requirements then there is no tricky work-around that I know of to slip in malicious characters on such a strict rule.

but the term "string" is very open. does that include punctuation? what kind, etc. If you allow standard injection characters as what you call a "String" then my answer is no longer sure.

But I still recommend mysql_real_escape_string() on all user submitted info, no matter how you try to purify it before hand.

Comment: Spot on if you preg_match against just [0-9a-z]... no malicious data can be entered there, as far as I know.. But yeah, I agree that all user input should not be trusted and should always be validated -- it should be a practiced whenever possible..

Answer (score 3):

This will be short answer...

Use **PDO**:

- Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

For example [Zend famework](http://framework.zend.com/) is using this engine.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But this is not answering to my question.

Comment: According to your fist question: Yes, it will be safe enough. But you should still use `mysql_real_escape_string()` because you are only human, as we all are. Anyway use PDO so you will not have to ask that question on SO and using PDO is very, very good practice with PHP. In other programming languages **you can't** do the query without defining type of column. Using PDO is vey elegant and modern way to use DB. (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a regex to match against valid input, and it succeeds, then the user input is valid. That being said, if you don't have any malicious characters in valid input (particularly quotes or potentially multibyte characters), then you don't need to call `mysql_real_escape_string`. The same principle applies to something like:

```
$user_in_num = intval( $_POST['in_num']); // Don't need mysql_real_escape_string here
```

So something like the following:

```
$subject = $_POST['string_input'];
if( !preg_match('/[^a-z0-9]/i', $subject)) 
{
    exit( 'Invalid input');
}
```

It is fine / safe to use `$subject` in an SQL query once the `preg_match` succeeds.

Comment: I would still use mysql_real_escape string. Why not? What if you mess up creating the regex?

Comment: @Galen - That's really not the point, especially for such a simple regex. A downvote for an indeterminate "What if...?" question is ignorant. What if you make **ANY** other programming mistake that causes a security vulnerability? Same principle applies here.

Comment: My point is there's no reason not to run everything through `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: @Galen - I do agree with you, but that wasn't the OP's question.

Comment: I know, im saying the answer should be you should always take the time to protect yourself.